# PixiJS resize renderer but keep ratio?

Tags: javascript, html, pixi.js

I'm making a game with PIXI.JS that's using detailed Pixel art. The game I want to design vertically oriented (perfect for smartphones) but I'd also like it to fit in a browser window with it's ratio in-tact. I'd also need all of the content to scale and remain in tact as well.

Can anyone help with this? I've done so much research that my head is starting to hurt, and I feel like I haven't gotten very far with it.

Comment: I'm not 100% what you want to achieve as I don't know what kind of game it is, from the description, so with the scaling and fitting in browser window do you mean like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/X9XexHw65aB5Sa6xSroZ?p=preview (use mouse scroll for scaling).
Or some kinda else?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty easy to resize the renderer in pixi. Just initialize a renderer. For example (a canvas with the id "renderer" is required):

```
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(width, height, {antialias: false, transparent: false, resolution: 1, view: document.getElementById("renderer")});
```

And then decide to resize your renderer if needed:

```
renderer.resize(newWidth, newHeight);
```

See https://pixijs.github.io/docs/PIXI.WebGLRenderer.html for reference.